# Are all bond-forming processes exothermic?

Tags: enthalpy

Are all bond-forming processes exothermic?

If so, why don't helium form bonds with neon?

Comment: Related: [Is Bond Formation “Strictly” Exothermic?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/13536/7951)

Comment: Downvoter: how could I make this question better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are, but

(1) a reaction only occurs spontaneously if it is *exergonic at the given temperature*, and

(2) it might not be the kind of bond you wanted. He and Ne like it much better with a van-der-Waals bond between them, and

(3) creating the spiecies that *can* bond can take a large amount of energy. Vaporising a solid, splitting diatomic gases, *forming some unheard of He+Ne radicals*, etc., and

(4) if the bond is endothermic, it simply won't form, because it is not a bound state.

Point 2-4 are basically redundand, just different ways to look at it.

Comment: why don't helium form bonds with neon?

Comment: Because any bond you could imagine, except a vdW-Bond, would be endothermic, i.e. not a bond. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_gas

Comment: So there are indeed endothermic bonds.

Comment: Those are not bonds, because they do not bind at all!

Comment: So you're saying that if I used magic to form this molecule: $\ce{He-N}$ then the single bond would not be a bond?

Comment: There is no such thing as magic. EoD.

Comment: I meant, if this molecule existed, the single bond would not be a bond?

Comment: "the single bond would not be a bond?" doesn't make any sense. Once you move away from covalent bonding, there is almost never such a thing as a single bond, double bond, triple bond, etc.

Answer (score -5):

i think that helium and neon are both noble gases and hence do not form bonds(because bonds are meant for those atoms who have more electrons or less electrons).yes bond forming is exothermic(courtesy https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090822024552AAB8qjv).