# What happens in an exothermic reaction at the atomic level?

Tags: thermodynamics

**Exothermic Reactions** are those chemical reactions in which heat is released.

How does this happen?

What I mean is where does  the heat energy come from? Which form of energy is converted to heat energy? What makes some reactions release heat? What affects the amount of heat energy released?

Thanks!

Comment: Exothermic reactions are the reactions in which relesed energy is more than that which was absorbed. It comes from the internal energy of the reacting species Eg.vibrarational energy.

Comment: Absorbed energy? I'm sorry, I don't understand quite what you mean by **absorbed energy** here...

Comment: To initiate a reaction we need to supply energy in any form which makes the reacting species overcome the activation energy

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITpDrdtGAmo) is a nice description from Richard Feynman.

Comment: What is the energy supplied when water reacts with quick lime to form slaked lime. $CaO$ + $H_{2}O$ $\longrightarrow$ $Ca(OH)_{2}$. This is an example of exothermic reaction

Comment: It would be the dissociation energy of water and lattice energy of CaO. Of course the reaction is self sustained at room temperature  because at this temperature the reacting molecules have sufficient energy. As the temperature is higher than the equilibrium temperature the reaction occurs spontaneously. As the temperature comparison is relative even if we don't supply energy (raise the temperature) the reaction occurs. This does not mean that there was no energy absorbed.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto That's a very nice video, but I believe Feynman's description of photosynthesis contains an error! AFAIK carbon fixation does not separate the carbon from the oxygen in CO2, but incorporated the whole molecule into the sugar it's creating. The oxygen plants release comes from water-splitting.

Comment: @gardenhead You are correct, he got that part wrong. Fortunately, he's going for a "feeling" of what happens, rather than a rigorous description, so it's acceptable for a lay audience.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> What happens in an exothermic reaction at the atomic level?

In a chemical reaction, bonds are broken and bonds are formed. For example, when elemental oxygen and hydrogen form water, we are breaking bonds in the elements and making heteroatomic bonds connecting hydrogen and oxygen atoms:
$$\ce{O2 + 2H2-> 2H2O}$$

To emphasize the bonds, we could also write:

$$\ce{O=O + H-H + H-H -> H-O-H + H-O-H}$$

In a thought experiment, we could first separate the elements into "isolated" atoms, and then recombine them to form water. Bond dissociation energies estimate how much energy it takes to separate bound atoms into "isolated" atoms. In the case of the example reaction, it takes less energy to break all the bonds of the reactants (one double bond connecting oxygen atoms and two single bonds connecting hydrogen atoms) than to break all the bonds of the products (four single bonds between oxygen and hydrogen atoms). As a result, there is an excess of energy that becomes available, resulting in an exothermic reaction.

> What affects the amount of heat energy released?

The reaction follows a more subtle path than completely ripping molecules apart into atoms and then making new molecules. However, because enthalpy is a state function, the result in terms of reaction enthalpy is the same. So the only thing that affects the reaction enthalpy is the set of reactants and products.

The amount of heat depends on how you set up the reaction. If the temperature before and after the reaction is the same, if the pressure is constant and there is no non-PV work, it is equal to the reaction enthalpy. If the reaction is used to do work (electrochemical cell, steam engine etc), if it is a photochemical reaction, if it gives off light, or if any other of the conditions given in the previous sentence are not met, that will affect the amount of heat transferred.

> Which form of energy is converted to heat energy?

The energy "comes from" the different energy of electronic states in the reactants and products. You can call this chemical energy, or a combination of kinetic and potential energy of the electrons. We see that electrons going from a higher energy state to a lower energy state give off energy when considering atomic spectra (sodium giving off a yellow light in the Bunsen burner, for example). In the case of reactions, electronic states are different between reactants and products not because they are in excited states, but because of the different configuration of nuclei giving rise to different electronic states.

> How does this happen?

Unless the reaction gives off energy directly (by emitting electromagnetic waves - rather rare), the available energy gets transformed into kinetic energy of the nuclei (e.g. molecular vibration), and then is transferred to the surrounding by the common ways of heat transfer until the system is at thermal equilibrium again. If the reaction is endothermic, some of the activation energy (provided by molecular collisions) is not "returned to the pool" but instead used to get the electrons into their higher energy states in the products (compared to the reactants), leading to a net heat transfer from surroundings to the chemical reaction.

Comment: The dissociation energy curves of O2 or H2 could be useful to illustrate how the potential and kinetic energies are reorganized. Here is a generic curve https://www.britannica.com/science/potential-energy-curve.

Comment: @Karsten on a different note, would you allow any user of the these sites to ask questions, comments despite their reputation numbers? (because nobody is an expert in every area, and even the experts do have the freedom to ask infant questions without being barred for rep-numbers when in doubt or when learning, understanding things)

Comment: @bonCodigo This would be a good question for meta. From the help pages: "The three most important activities on Chemistry Stack Exchange are Asking, Answering and Editing - none of which require any reputation at all!". https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: @Karsten well, context of my comment was more to do with that rep (whether 10 or 10,000) should not be taken as a measure to assumed a user knows everything or stop them from asking questions in their own learning process. There was a person who was practically throwing tantrums at me (often others too) hideously pointing at my reps in comparison to a question I was trying to solve;

Comment: @Karsten that sorta behaviour in the community sites like this clearly not welcoming, and `the arrogant` went on to take their revenge by downvoting practically most of my questions and answers on this site at the expense of his own reps. That was sick! if I was a chem expert I would be teaching in an university and asking my colleagues, wouldn't bother asking questions here...

Comment: @bonCodigo We try to be welcoming while also allowing each single user to decide on what they want to upvote, downvote, comment on or ignore. This freedom allows for community-based evaluation of answers, but also allows for occasional frustration, disagreement or disappointment. You are welcome to ask questions at any level, and I expect everyone to treat you with respect.

Comment: @Karsten Been here for awhile, I can appreciate the nature of the various. This wasn't just my experience. We get to see a thing or two off here. I have only experienced it once last year and yes ignored it. I guess a human frustration is perhaps still tolerable compared to what it may be with darn AI chatbots...if it comes to conquer the sites/communities. Good day!

Answer (score 3):

An exothermic reaction is one which results in heat or light being released by the system and absorbed into the surroundings, usually referred to as a change in enthalpy. Enthalpy $H$ is the energy contained within the bonds of a molecule.  This amount, the bond energy, is roughly the amount of enthalpy necessary to break the bond.

### Important Concept!

#### An input of energy is always required to break a bond ($\Delta H\gt0$) which means the process is endothermic.

#### Anytime a bond is formed energy is released ($\Delta H\lt0$), so forming bonds is exothermic.

Try not to get the above $\Delta H$'s mixed up with any $\Delta H_\mathrm r$. The above is relevant to breaking/creating single bonds; reactions are dynamic processes that are much more complicated that formulas make them appear to be.

In an exothermic reaction there is less energy in the products' bonds than there was in the reactants' and when that energy difference is absorbed the the surrounds it causes a positive increase of heat in the surroundings. The difference in enthalpy can be calculated with the following equation:

$$\Delta H_\mathrm r=\Sigma H_\mathrm{f(\text{products})}-\Sigma H_\mathrm{f(\text{reactants})}$$

$H_\mathrm f$ is the enthalpy of formation, defined as the change in enthalpy when one mole of a substance is formed from its pure elements. You will most likely see it used along with a degree symbol, $H^\circ_\mathrm f$ indicates this reaction takes place at STP. You will usually be able to look up the necessary $H^\circ_\mathrm f$ in a reference table, but the amount is related to bonds strength, length, charge imbalance, and some other attributes.

Exothermic reactions have a negative change in enthalpy $(\Delta H_\mathrm r\lt0)$ The energy released during an exothermic reaction is the difference in bond energy between the reactants and the products. The energy lost by the reaction becomes energy gained by the system which will result in an increase of heat (or light). The difference in signs for the change in enthalpy of the reaction and change in energy of the system is a common point of confusion, so be sure to remember this:

**Exothermic:**

- Energy flows from the system into the surroundings, $(\Delta H_\mathrm r\lt0)$

**Endothermic:**

- Energy flows from the surroundings into the system. $(\Delta H_\mathrm r\gt0)$

Comment: Thanks, by the way, what level Chemistry is this?

Comment: This is the level I was taught when I first took chemistry in 10th grade; I didn't take any intro level courses at undergrad but I imagine this would be covered in the second semester of the first course, along with a lab component.
    
If anything is unclear or you want to know more feel free to ask; I'm extremely rusty and the summary I wrote is pretty rough by I can definitely explain more if you have any specific questions.

Comment: @Rajdeep_Sindhu hey I didn't realize we weren't supposed to have casual conversations in the comments; looks like some got deleted. If you ever wanna chat about chemistry you can find me on Twitter or telegram, same name as here. Cheers

Comment: There is also [chat] for casual conversation, and yes, obsolete comments will get cleaned up occasionally. This may be somewhat related: [Is Bond Formation “Strictly” Exothermic?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/13536/4945)